# Zend ini routing limitless subpages

Tags: zend-framework, subroutine

Currently I'm working on a system which has build-in pages. The pages work with parent and child pages which means sub-paging works. Now, i've been searching on the web all morning to find out how I should write my routing to create a (unlimited) sub-page mechanism where you have the :language/page/parent/child-1/child-2/child-3/:alias... and so on. The :alias in my example corresponds to a DB table field (has always to be on the end).

```
[routes]

routes.language.type                                        = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.language.route                                       = ":lang"
routes.language.defaults.lang                               = "en"

routes.language.chains.frontend_page.type                   = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.language.chains.frontend_page.route                  = "page/:alias"
routes.language.chains.frontend_page.defaults.module        = "default"
routes.language.chains.frontend_page.defaults.controller    = "index"
routes.language.chains.frontend_page.defaults.action        = "index"
routes.language.chains.frontend_page.defaults.alias         = "index"
```

This is how my (simple) routing currently looks like. I guess many others with me are searching a good solution for this problem. So if there is a genius out there who is willing to explain... please =D !

Best regards

Comment: Any special reasons for caring about the url so much?
If you just want to do it to show the hierarchy of pages, then  why not use a breadcrumb for it?

Comment: I totaly agree with you, but I think its better if you show the parent pages in the url aswell (SEO related). Currently I just have one single alias like you prefer aswell. Thanks for your reply btw!